# Why .add layers can`t be done when creating Keras model (NoneType error)

Tags: python, keras

When I'm creating a model and adding some layers directly to create generator, this generates `NoneType` object.

Code:

```
network = Sequential().add(Flatten())
network.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

This drops error:

```
AttributeError                          
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-4636db57f4d3> in <module>()
      1
      2 network = Sequential().add(Flatten())
----> 3 network.add(Dropout(0.5))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

My question is: why we cannot use `.add` **when** creating keras model?

Answer (score 1):

The function `add` from the class `Sequential` does not return the model. It is a so called void function (non value returning function) which in Python returns `None`. You need to do this steps separately:

```
network = Sequential()
network.add(Flatten())
network.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

Comment: Firstly, .add is a method, not function. This is true, that *method* returns nothing, but when performing 
 `network = Sequential();
   network.add(Flatten()).add(Dropout(0.5)) ` this also returns none object for network, even if value for network is not rewrited.